# Only in lines with a specific string replace another string

Tags: scripts, text-processing

Shell script to find the occurences of the word "here" and only in those lines, replace the word "this" with the word "that". Rest all the other lines are printed as they were.

Comment: $ sed '/here/ s/this/that/' test

Comment: Have you looked for an answer ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525592/find-and-replace-inside-a-text-file-from-a-bash-command

Comment: @guyd That question is different. That is a direct replacement of X for Y. This is a replacement of X for Y conditional upon the presence of Z.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have `file.txt` containing these two lines:

```
here is this
but not this
```

You can run the following `sed` command to replace "this" with "that" on all lines containing the word "here", leaving all other lines untouched:

```
sed '/\bhere\b/ s/\bthis\b/that/g' file.txt
```

Note that the `\b` in the patterns symbolizes word boundaries, i.e. the beginning or end of a word. Without those, e.g. "there" would also match.

Output:

```
here is that
but not this
```

Read `man sed` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` (i.e. `GNU Awk` in Ubuntu) solution could look like this:

```
awk '{ if ( /\yhere\y/ ) gsub ( /\ythis\y/ , "that" ); print }'
```

`\y` in `awk` equals `\b` in `sed`, whose importance here [@ByteCommander already explained](https://askubuntu.com/a/980769/507051). Compare this example:

```
$ awk '{if(/here/)gsub(/\ythis\y/,"that");print}' <<EOL
> here is this
> here is athis
> there is this
> EOL
here is that
here is athis
there is that

$ awk '{if(/\yhere\y/)gsub(/\ythis\y/,"that");print}' <<EOL
> here is this
> here is athis
> there is this
> EOL
here is that
here is athis
there is this
```

#### Explanations

- `if ( conditional expression ) action` – `awk`'s `if` statement: if the currently processed line contains *conditional expression*, then do *action*
- `/\yhere\y/` – regular expression matching the word “here”
- `gsub(x,y)` – `g`lobally ( = multiple times per line if necessary) `sub`stitute *`x`* by *`y`*
- `print` – print the currently processed line